# Reading from file to different class objects

Tags: c++, arrays, class, sorting, fstream

I'm a beginner in C++ coding and I have a question regarding reading lines from a file into specific class objects, one of which is an array.

My class object:

```
const int SIZE_OF = 5;

class Student
{
public:
    Student();
    Student(const Student &);
    Student(string, int, int, int, int, int);
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, Student& S);
    void display();
private:
   string lastName;
   int grades[SIZE_OF];
};
```

CPP file to define functions:

```
Student::Student()
{
    int i;
    string lastName = "default";
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        grades[i] = 0;
    }
}

Student::Student(const Student & S)
{
    int i;
    lastName = S.lastName;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        grades[i] = S.grades[i];
    }
}

Student::Student(string S, int a, int b, int c, int d, int e)
{
    lastName = S;
    grades[0] = a;
    grades[1] = b;
    grades[2] = c;
    grades[3] = d;
    grades[4] = e;
}

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, Student& S)
{
    std::string line;
    std::getline(in, line);
    in >> S.lastName >> S.grades[0] >> S.grades[1] >> S.grades[2] >> S.grades[3] >> S.grades[4];
    getline(in, S.lastName);
    return in;
}

void Student::display()
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    double average;
    cout << "Last Name: " << lastName << endl;
    cout << "Grades: " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << grades[i] << endl;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + grades[i];
    }
    average = sum / 5;
    cout << "Average: " << average;    
}
```

What I need to do is read from a file and save the name under the `lastName` object of the `Student` class. Then I need to save each of the grades in the array object. Then I need to have a new `Student` class object for the next name and repeat the process for 4 names. The file I'm reading from:

```
George
75,85,95,100,44
Peter
100,100,100,100,100
Frank
44,55,66,77,88
Alfred
99,88,77,66,55
```

Comment: what I seem to not understand is how to read the file into different class objects. For example I would have 4 objects of the student class and the first 2 lines would have to be read to the first object, then the next two lines are the 2nd object, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

your following function seems to be wrong:

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, Student& S)
{
    std::string line;
    std::getline(in, line);
    in >> S.lastName >> S.grades[0] >> S.grades[1] >> S.grades[2] >> S.grades[3] >> S.grades[4];
    getline(in, S.lastName);
    return in;
}
```

You read lastName twice, you do not ignore the ',' character... try something like this:

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, Student& S)
{
    char dummy;
    in >> S.lastName >> S.grades[0] 
       >> dummy >> S.grades[1] 
       >> dummy >> S.grades[2] 
       >> dummy >> S.grades[3] 
       >> dummy >> S.grades[4];

    return in;
}
```

UPDATE:
  If you consider spaces inside lastName, you should have to change the first line to use std::getline as follows:

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, Student& S)
{
    char dummy;
    std::getline(in, S.lastName) 
    in >> S.grades[0] 
       >> dummy >> S.grades[1] 
       >> dummy >> S.grades[2] 
       >> dummy >> S.grades[3] 
       >> dummy >> S.grades[4];
    in.ignore(); // remove last '\n'
    return in;
}
```

Then:

```
int main()
{
    Student s;
    std::vector<Student> all;

    while (cin>>s)
      all.push_back(s);
}
```

...and...enough updates!

Comment: thank you, I'm assuming I do not need getline since there are no spaces.

Comment: More along the line of you don't need `getline` because you don't care about the lines. Mixing `getline` and `>>` is problematic because  `>>` can leave line endings in the stream as booby traps for `getline`. Remember to test the state of the `istream` before trying to use the `Student` you just read into. If any of the reads failed, you can't trust the `Student` and the `istream` will be in an unusable state.

Comment: I fixed that but what I seem to not understand is how to read the file into different class objects. For example I would have 4 objects of the student class and the first 2 lines would have to be read to the first object, then the next two lines are the 2nd object, and so on.